# Javascript - Jquery, bind a dynamic selector with 'On' method (not a string)

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, selector

I want to use the 'On' function to attach a event because the others are deprecied(live, delegate,click...).

But the problem is : if we generate objects, we need to use a selector in parameters and this parameter is a string!!

Sample :
(context : dynamic table)

```
//Wrong way

$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});

//Good way

$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Now How I do if I want use 'find' method  in order to avoid that

```
    // ?? (find div)
    $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr > ul > li > ul > li > div", function(event){
            alert($(this).text());
        });

   // What I would like to do
    $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", $(this).find("div"), function(event){
            alert($(this).text());
        });

   //and I don't want to do this :
    $("#dataTable tbody").find('div').on("click", function(event){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
```

Thank you !

Comment: Instead of `"tr > ul > li > ul > li > div"`, just set a class on the DIV (btw, you can't have an UL directly inside a TR). Also, this smells like you're using tables for layout.

Comment: I don't use table, I just find a simple way to show my problem.
Of course, I can use Class, Id... but I want use {parent(), children(), closest(),...} How I can do that ?

Comment: The second argument of the `on()` method is a selector string. You cannot use jQuery methods here. It has to be a string. So either `'ul > li > ul > li > div'`, or just `'ul ul div'`, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *working* equivalent to:

```
// What I would like to do
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", $(this).find("div"), function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

is...

```
// What I would like to do
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", 'div', function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you to target `div`'s inside the nested list, then you *might* be able to get away with:

```
// What I would like to do
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", 'ul ul div', function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

... but it depends if you have *other* `ul`'s in your `tbody`; you only need to be specific enough in your selector to remove the other elements from consideration. Very rarely would you need to be as specific as `tr > ul > li > ul > li > div`, and in that case it'd be best to apply a class to an element nearer the `div` (or the `div` itself) and select around that instead.

Also note that it is only `live()` that is depreciated. At the time of writing (1.7.2) `delegate()` is not, although I believe it will be in 1.8.

There is no talk of depreciating `click()` or it's shortcut counterparts.

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to select only DIV elements which are inside nested lists (UL inside UL). Your code selects all DIV elements within the table.

Comment: Exactly, I want only DIV elements inside nested lists.
The method 'find' was may a bad idea... If I need to use a children() or closest() function.
The main goal is : I want to use the very practicals 'JQuery selection methods' with dynamic element.

Comment: @Matt Also, your first code block does not work, since `$(this)` doesn't refer to the TBODY element...

Comment: @user988587: I've updated my question to explain how to select the `div` in a nested `ul`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I can't see in the question where the OP has said he *wants* `$(this)` to be the `TBODY` element? If he wants it, he can use `event.delegateTarget` in place of `this`.

Comment: @Matt That is implied. The OP is doing event delegation, and he wants to select only those elements which are descendants of the event delegation root element - in this case, `"#dataTable tbody"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select DIV elements which are inside nested lists, then this would be one way to do it:

```
$( '#foo' ).on( 'click', 'ul ul div', function () {
```

However, I recommend classes. Just set a class on your DIV elements and then:

```
$( '#foo' ).on( 'click', '.bar', function () {
```